# Cant run eclipse on my Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I installed the latest version of Java and when I try to run eclipse it says:

> Version `1.6.0_65` of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: `1.8` or greater is required.

I searched many forums and found the `java -version` command. When I run from the terminal I get:

> java version "1.6.0_65" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-466.1, mixed mode)

But when I open Java on my system preferences it says I have `1.8`.

Why? What do I do?

Comment: Install the Java 8 **JDK** from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Answer (score 1):

It says `1.6` because it is the pre-installed version in your system. But in order to install different version of Java, you need to install the latest development kit from Oracle's website i.e. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html